# get the abs value of long long integer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I try to use the codes below to get the abs value of a long long type integer;

```
long long v=abs(originalValue);
```

It works as I expected until the value of v exceeds 1073741824 (1G)

If v is 2147482648, abs(v) is -2147482648.

If v is 10737418240, abs(v) is -2147482648 also.

I do not understand what causes these happened.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `llabs()` instead:

```
long long v = llabs(originalValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

`abs` takes an int as an argument, for a long long use [llabs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/llabs.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/llabs)